# doxygen source code links not working in python project

Tags: doxygen

I am using doxygen to document the contents of my cgi-bin folder on my apache web server. The doxygen html pages have links to source code but they stopped working. Is there a specific expert configuration parameter required?

Comment: "Stopped working" is a bit of a vague fault report. What did you get in the past? What are you getting now? What changed?

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using. In the title you mention python, but further on no mentioning of it. Please show us some code and the settings (different from the default doxygen configuration) you used.